# Using MySQL date in a formula with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am ultimately trying to get the difference in days between two dates (ContractDate and CloseDate). They dates are already stored in the MySQL DB in the format 0000-00-00, but I cannot get them to be inserted into the formula correctly. I am using the following query for this and some other items.

```
$q_groups = mysql_query("SELECT CONCAT(contacts.last_name, ', ', contacts.first_name) as Name,
                        loans.subject_property as SubjectProperty, loans.fKeyUserLoanOfficer,
                        loan_types.name as LoanType, loans.closed_on as CloseDate, loans.contract_date as ContractDate, loans.amount as Amount, loan_status_types.name as LoanStatus,
                        loans._id, loans.fKeyReferral
                        FROM `loans`
                        LEFT JOIN `loan_status_types` ON (loans.fKeyLoanDetail = loan_status_types._id)
                        LEFT JOIN `loan_status` ON (loan_status._id = loan_status_types.fKeyType)
                        LEFT JOIN `loan_types` ON (loans.fKeyLoanType = loan_types._id)
                        LEFT JOIN `contacts` ON (contacts._id = loans.fKeyContact)
                        WHERE loans.fKeyGroup = '{$gid}' AND loan_status.name LIKE '%Closed%'
                        ORDER BY loans.closed_on DESC")
                        or die(ErrorLog::handle(mysql_error()));
```

What I want to do is have the two dates (ContractDate and CloseDate) from query above populate the dates below (in RED):

```
$start = strtotime("2012-08-16");
$end = strtotime("2012-06-28");
$dayz = ($start - $end) / (60 * 60 * 24);
```

When I view the DB, the "closed_on" field, has a date of 2012-08-16, when I view the "contract_date" field, the date is 2012-06-28...but I cannot get this information to be inserted correctly without an error or no data being displayed at all.

** What I am having issue with is...how do I replace the static dates with the field data? **

Thanks, Ed

Comment: I think you should clarify your question. How do you put your data from SQL into your formula? Why don't you use SUB_DATE ? Etc...

Comment: I am able to get the date difference part to work if I paste the dates into the formula. But I need to pull the dates from the db and insert them into the formula. IE... $start = strtotime("DB_DATE_TO_GO_HERE");

Comment: so is the query not returning anything? or ?

Comment: Dagon - Yes, either nothing is returned or it crashed when I try changing the formula.

Comment: the word is *query* not formula, you are confusing us here. what error are you getting? and how are you retrieving the results from the query

Comment: It's really not a good idea to use `mysql_query` in new applications as it's extremely hazardous if not used correctly. For instance, if your `$gid` is a variable pulled in from `$_SESSION`, `$_GET` or `$_POST` then it could be used to destroy your entire database. [Escape your SQL correctly](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or there may be serious consequences if this code is used in a public-facing web site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
TO_DAYS(closed_on) - TO_DAYS(contract_date) AS `dayz`
```

Added to your existing query:

```
$q_groups = mysql_query("SELECT CONCAT(contacts.last_name, ', ', contacts.first_name) as Name,
                        loans.subject_property as SubjectProperty, loans.fKeyUserLoanOfficer,
                        loan_types.name as LoanType, loans.closed_on as CloseDate, loans.contract_date as ContractDate, loans.amount as Amount, loan_status_types.name as LoanStatus,
                        loans._id, loans.fKeyReferral,
                        TO_DAYS(loans.closed_on) - TO_DAYS(loans.contract_date) AS `dayz`
                        FROM `loans`
                        LEFT JOIN `loan_status_types` ON (loans.fKeyLoanDetail = loan_status_types._id)
                        LEFT JOIN `loan_status` ON (loan_status._id = loan_status_types.fKeyType)
                        LEFT JOIN `loan_types` ON (loans.fKeyLoanType = loan_types._id)
                        LEFT JOIN `contacts` ON (contacts._id = loans.fKeyContact)
                        WHERE loans.fKeyGroup = '{$gid}' AND loan_status.name LIKE '%Closed%'
                        ORDER BY loans.closed_on DESC")
                        or die(ErrorLog::handle(mysql_error()));
```

With the additional benefit of correctness, as simply dividing timestamps by the number of seconds in a day won't work right across DST boundaries and such.

Comment: Nice...now all I needed to do was place {$row['dayz']} on the page and it worked great! Thanks to all who helped.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you [let MySQL do the data manipulations](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html). It has a much better range of functions than PHP, as well as a native date/time datatype. You can add and subtract times and dates in unambiguous language and you don't have the problems of roundtrips to and from Unix timestamps.

And you *don't* want to do it with Unix timestamps! This because for date manipulations it offers too much precision: second vs day, which is a good sign it's the wrong solution. They also don't allow for things like time zones and daylight-saving transitions and trying to handle that yourself is the start of a long slippery slope. Much *much* better to use proper date-handling functions because they've already been extensively debugged and Just Work.

You could also use the new PHP [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) library but if your dates are coming from MySQL and are going back into MySQL, just use MySQL; it's less conversion.

Answer (score 0):

If you are stuck with PHP you could use [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) object:

```
  $datetime1 = new DateTime('2009-10-11');  
  $datetime2 = new DateTime('2009-10-13');
  $interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
  echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
```

[DateTime::diff()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) manual.

Comment: Giovanni - what I don't know how to do is get the dates to be inserted into the formula (in RED).

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the data in your database, I would recommend using that since it's faster as staticsan pointed out.

An example would be something like this, however you would be replacing the static dates below with field data from the table:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF('2010-10-08 18:23:13', '2010-09-21 21:40:36') AS days;
```

Comment: Paul- that is what I am having issue with...how do I replace the static dates with the field data.

Comment: You can use the field expressions from your original query in place of the static data used in the example in this answer.

Comment: You would just replace those with the start_date and end_date fields (or whatever they're called in your db)